# Enum vs cache? Which one is better

Tags: caching, enums

I just found out that some co_workers are using Enum a lot. And using Enum as some kind of data store for some lists, like status list,  role list, etc.. And I am not sure if this is a good way to deal with this kind of data. I would like to put some data into DB and then read them into cache instead of putting the data into the code itself.

Comment: Enumerated types do not store data, they name it.  Keeping data in the database and referring to it with enums is entirely possible, and the one has no connection with the other.  The exception would be if there's another database table connecting code values with their meanings.  Moreover, this is fairly subjective, and doesn't really belong here.  A cleaned-up version that identified the issues would be appropriate for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is the value configurable like types of animals or is it fixed like gender or quarters?

Comment: Matthew: all kind of data, like genders, like statuses, like Airlines, like countries, like code environments....

Comment: David: Yes, you are right that Enums are used to name data. But Enums are also can be used to store data (Even this is not the right way to use them). I found some helper classes to read Enums and Enum description and bind them to drop down controls. I think this is the site for all kinds of programming issues. There is no indication that this topic should go somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

The decision of `enum` vs. database table depends on whether you expect additional values to be added/removed while the system is in production.

For example:

Use `enum` for:

- Payment method (cash, check or credit card)
- Billing frequency (daily, weekly, monthly, quarterly)
- Gender
- Status

Use a database table for:

- Carrier for delivery (FedEx, UPS, ???)
- Product category (books, music, games, ???)
- Airline

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own quetsion. It will be the political correct answer "It depends.....".
This is 50%-50% question. 
For developers who like Enums, Enum can be very helpful and the code can be very clear...
For developers who hate Enums, Enum is nothing but Const in another name and everytime there is a new status added, you have to add this new status to the Enum, .....